# C++: Updating binary search tree using a recursive search function?

Tags: c++, templates, binary-search-tree

I'm in the middle of making a binary search tree that stores Items of type MechPart, which stores an int `quantity` and a string `code`. The MechParts are generated by reading from a text file and storing their data. A separate text file called MonthlyUpdate.txt is used to read a list of MechParts in the tree and then update their quantities. For example:

> MechPart A0001's quantity = 12
>
> MonthlyUpdate.txt says A0001's quantity = 6
>
> Run an update function that finds A0001 in the tree
>
> Replace it with the updated quantity value of 6 (12 - 6).

Here's the two functions that perform this task:

```
    void DBInterface::updateFromFile(string f_Name) 
{
    ifstream file (f_Name.c_str());
    string line;

    MechPart tmp_mp;

    if (file.is_open())
    {
        std::getline(file, line);
        while (std::getline (file, line))
        {
            std::istringstream iss (line);
            int q=0;
            int pos=0;
            pos = line.find('\t',0); //find position of blank space
            string tmp_str = line.substr(0,pos); //create a substring
            string tmp_str1 = line.substr((pos+1), string::npos);
            stringstream ss (tmp_str1);
            ss >> q;

            tmp_mp.set_code(tmp_str); //set code
            tmp_mp.set_quantity(q);
            MechPart currentQuantity;
            currentQuantity = tree.quantitySearch(tree.getRoot(), tmp_mp);
            tmp_mp.set_quantity((currentQuantity.get_quantity()) + q);

            tree.update(tree.getRoot(), tmp_mp);
            cout << "Current node data: " << tmp_mp.get_code() << " | " << tmp_mp.get_quantity() << endl;


        }
    }
```

and BSTree.template:

```
template <typename Item>
Item BSTree<Item>::quantitySearch(BTNode<Item>* q_ptr, Item obj)
{
    if (q_ptr == NULL)
    {
    //POINTER IS NULL
    }
    else if (q_ptr->data() == obj)
    {
        return q_ptr->data();
    }

    else if (obj > q_ptr->data()) 
    { //WORK ON RIGHT SIDE
        quantitySearch(q_ptr->get_right(), obj);
    }
    else
    {
    //work on left side
        quantitySearch(q_ptr->get_left(), obj);

    }

}
```

The search goes through the tree and locates a `MechPart` with the same part name `code` as the parameter and then returns that `MechPart`.
I've been running the code through GDB debugger. I have it displaying `currentQuantity.get_quantity()` to validate the returned `MechPart`'s quantity is correct, however i am getting very large numbers for some reason. What is also confusing me is that in the `MechPart` constructor it assigns a value of 0 to `quantity`.

Eventually the `updateFromFile()` function gives me a segmentation fault, so something is very wrong here but I can't work out what as yet.

Comment: When you are recursively searching, you need to return the node that's found. You are only doing that for one `if-else` block. In the other cases, you are discarding the return value.

Comment: Bit harsh. I'm very new to this.

Comment: @a_pradhan I'm not sure what your point is. The function keeps calling itself with different nodes passed in until it reaches the correct node, and then returns it's data (in this case, MechPart).

Comment: Only one control path returns a value...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursive functions need to return their recursive calls back up to their caller for them to work properly. Look at the classic factorial example of recursion:

```
int factorial(int n) {
    if (n == 1) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return n*factorial(n-1);
    }
}
```

As others have pointed out, your `quantitySearch` function only returns `q_ptr->data()` but never returns the return value from the recursive `quantitySearch` calls. I would start there and I would strongly suggest adding in `cout` statements in the recursive function to get a complete picture of what's happening "under the hood"